# Can you help me to correct this "net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" Chrome error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, redirect

I have a problem with ajax POST when my website is integrated in iframe. Only some users have the error in Chrome. I put a screenshot of the console error (send by user).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYfwt.jpg)

The concerned javascript is in /js/open.min.js :

```
/* (c) 2019 Lockee.fr */
function openLock(){
    if($("#inputcode").val() != ""){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',  
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: homeURL + 'ajax-open.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {id : $("#inputid").val(), code : $("#inputcode").val(), top : $("#inputtop").val()},
            timeout: 3000,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.open == 0){
                    $("#wrongcode").fadeIn(0).delay(1500).fadeOut(0);
                } else {
                    if(data.redirect == 1){
                        if(data.top == 1){
                            top.location.href = data.content;
                        } else {
                            location.href = data.content;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $("#contentlock").html(data.content);
                        $("#isclose").hide();
                        $("#isopen").show();
                        $("#report").show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
function closeLock(){
    lock.clearCode();
    $("#contentlock").html("");
    $("#isopen").hide();
    $("#report").hide();
    $("#isclose").show();
}
```

The PHP code :

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
if((!empty($_POST["id"]))&&(!empty($_POST["code"]))){
    $id = addslashes($_POST['id']);
    $code = htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);
    $infos = lockInfo($id);
    if(($infos['action'] == "L")&&($_POST['top'] == 1)){
        $top = 1;
        $redirect = 1;
        $content = $infos["content"];
    } else if($infos['action'] == "L"){
        $redirect = 1;
        $top = 0;
        $content = $infos["content"];
    } else {
        $redirect = 0;
        $top = 0;
        $content = displayContent($infos["action"], $infos["content"], $infos["linked"], false);
    }
    $open = 1;
    if($infos['code'] == $code){
        $open = 1;
    } else {
        $open = 0;
    }
} else {
    $open = 0;
}
if($open == 0){
    $content = "";
}
$file = ["open" => $open, "content" => $content, "redirect" => $redirect, "top" => $top];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($file);
?>
```

This is an example which is not working for some users :

[The code to open integrated lock is "123"](https://view.genial.ly/5f3b9adc9fdd7f0d1ffd9eba)

Thank's for your help !

Comment: I have added the php code of the file.